# Calculate date time by adding / subtracting local offset [ Convert any date time , to UTC time format]

Tags: ios, swift, timezone-offset

I am getting Flight :

1. Scheduled Date and Scheduled Time and flight local offset value in service

Now it is required to find the difference between my datetime ( local timezone ) and the datetime ( coming from service ).

Problem : Difference B/W between my local datetime and Flight Scheduled Date and Time ( could be of any TIMEZONE , so in the service i am getting LOCALOFFSET VALUE like : "-7:00" or "-6:00"

E.g : 
Flight DateTime    : 2018-12-28 05:15:00 , Local offset : -06:00
My Local DateTime  : 2018-12-28 14:08:00

Need to find the difference ?

Thanks

Comment: You are not getting the times in UTC timezone for both flight time and local time?

Comment: yes i am not getting date time in utc timezone , it is in other local time in their time zone , so i need to use their local offset to find the exact time

Comment: You surely tried *something*. Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that this does not look like a “write the code for me” question!

Comment: _A [Date](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date) is independent of a particular calendar or time zone._ So just use [`Date.timeIntervalSince(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779636-timeintervalsince) and you're done.

Comment: @Carpsen90 thanks for reminding the criteria for asking question , i forgot to append code along with the question , but somehow i tried to solve the issue. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by using localoffset coming from service and with the method available in swift , TimeZone(secondsFromGMT:offset) :

```
func findFlightTimeInUTCFormat(dateString:String, localOffSet:String) -> Date? {
        let gmtTimeString = dateString

        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -6*60*60)
        var finalDate:Date?
        // original string in GMT
        guard let date = formatter.date(from: gmtTimeString) else {
            print("can't convert time string")
            return finalDate
        }
        finalDate = date
        return finalDate
    }
```

Solved and its working fine.